# Некорректно работает скрипт

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток! Такая проблема со скриптом - в первый раз скрипт отрабатывает нормально, но если второй раз нажать показать все, блок сначала раскрывается и тут же закрывается. В чем может быть проблема?  
Сам скрипт:

```
$('.more-refs').on('click', function(){
  var height2 = $('.trr').height() > $('.trl').height()
     ? $('.trr').outerHeight(true) : $('.trl').outerHeight(true);
  $('#mpa-refs').animate({'height': height2+5}, 800, function(){
    $('.more-refs').text('свернуть').attr('class', 'less-refs');

    $('.less-refs').on('click', function(){
      $('#mpa-refs').animate({'height':'500px'}, 800, function(){
        $('.less-refs').text('показать все').attr('class', 'more-refs');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Пояснение - в блоке есть две таблицы, я нахожу с большей высотой и раскрываю блок на высоту этой таблицы

Comment: @woland, на будущее - чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора

Comment: добавьте разметку html и желательно сделайте jsfiddle пример.

Comment: Наверно это из-за того, что на тексте на момент второго нажатия висит сразу два обработчика, которые срабатывают в порядке навешивания.  
Это происходит потому, что после:  

    $('.more-refs').text('свернуть').attr('class', 'less-refs');
Текст является элементом двух классов: more-refs и less-refs.  
Как-то так, извините, нет времени тестировать, но долго никто Вам не отвечает, поэтому пусть хоть такая наводка будет.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FYPtU/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё из-за того что событие навешивается на элемент а не на селектор, чтобы повесить на селектор используйте .on в стиле устаревшего .live:

```
$(document).on('click', '.more', function () {
    var height = $('.srr').height() > $('.srl').height() ? $('.srr').outerHeight(true) : $('.srl').outerHeight(true);
    $('#search_results').css({
        'ovreflow': 'visible'
    }).animate({
        'height': height + $('.srl').position().top + 5
    }, 800, function () {

        $('.more').text('свернуть').attr('class', 'less');

    });
});
$(document).on('click', '.less', function () {
    $('#search_results').css({
        'overflow': 'hidden'
    }).animate({
        'height': '200px'
    }, 800, function () {
        $('.less').text('показать все').attr('class', 'more');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/FYPtU/1/